# Java Compilation error 12 : error: <identifier> expected : Initializing and declaring of variable in separate statement .

Tags: java

While compiling below piece of code, getting error as "error:  expected" :

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Hello h=new Hello();
         System.out.println(h.a);

    }
}

class Hello {

    int a;
    a=10;
    /*{
    a=10
    }

}*/ //Putting the reference variable inside the Instance block .
```

However if declare and initialize variable "a" in the same statement(int a=10;)inside class Hello then not getting error .

Comment: `a=10` is not valid in that place, simple as that.

Comment: @litelite, you can but have to put it in a block statement like `{ a = 10;}`

Comment: @AxelH Bad advise. Why confuse him with  an initializer block? Plain `int a = 10` gets the job done.

Comment: @GhostCat, agreed, but he said (not OP, but he have deleted his comment now...) that we couldn't have that statement outside of a method which is incorrect, block statement are a think. Without the comment this look like a bad advise :p PS : I never look at the simplicity of a code when commenting, it could/should be a [mcve] after all ;)

Comment: Agree with you all, but my doubt why do i have to declare and initialize in same statement and how declaring and then initializing variable is different from this ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have a floating initializer statement, you need to have something like the following:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Hello h=new Hello();
         System.out.println(h.a);

    }
}

class Hello {

    int a = 10; //changed this line

}
```

When a variable is simply named, such as below, it is declared. Declaring a variable creates a memory allocation, defines the variable type (e.g. `int`, `char` etc) and gives the variable a name (in your case `a`).

When you initialize a variable, it all the above information is already known, you simply change the variable from its default value to a new one.

The reason you can't initialize the variable from within the `class Test` is rules set by the creators (and maintainers) of Java. Interestingly when you try the following Eclipse prevents you from compiling:

```
public class Test {
    int i;
    i = 10;
}
```

So I thought it may be a safety feature of the IDE, so I ran from command line:

[image: example]

And that flagged up as an identifier expected error. Simply put, Java was created in mind that when you create a class level variable it must be declared and initialized in the same line, or just declared, and the software which translates from Java code -> Bytecode -> Machine code (the JVM, Java Virtual Machine), has not been made to cope with multi-line initializations at that scope level.

Comment: what do you mean by floating initializer statement? Also putting the instance variable "a" inside a block works fine too . Why do i need to declare and initialize the variable in same statement ?

Comment: I updated with more information, I hope this helps. I had to do some exploring myself before finding a good answer!